# Add new column based on Two columns with Conditions met

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have data source where we track equipment. I want to introduce a new column which is based on two columns. If Column 1 Says "US" and Column 2 says "In-Transit", it should return value "INBOUND" else if column 2 says "In-Transit" and column 1 says any other country other than US, it should return value "OutBound"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEIql.png)

| Maintenance Plant | Current Status |
| --- | --- |
| UK | Available |
| UK | In-Transit |
| US | In-Transit |
| US | Available |
| US | In-Transit |
| US | In Repair |
| Mexico | In-Transit |
| Canada | In-Transit |
| Canada | Available |
| US | In-Transit |
| US | In-Transit |
| Canada | In-Transit |
| Mexico | Available |
| Canada | Available |
| US | In Repair |

I tried formula
if [Maintenance Plant]=US and [Current Status]=In-Transit, "INBOUND" else "OUTBOUND"

It gave error

Comment: I tried below formula.                                                                                                                              if([Current Status]="IN-TRANSIT") then switch ( [Maintenance Plants]=US, "INBOUND") else "OUTBOUND")

Answer (score 0):

```
Column = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    AND([Maintenance Plant]="US",[Current Status]="In-Transit"), "INBOUND",
    AND([Maintenance Plant]<>"US",[Current Status]="In-Transit"),"OutBound",
    BLANK())
```

[image]